# Underground post apocalypse children story

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic, underground-civilization

I remember a book possibly published in the '70s or '80s. In the story a boy grows up in a cavern. Life sounds pretty primitive. He gathers lichen for food (I think), and it's imperative that the home fire never goes out since that is the only source of light or heat for cooking.

The leader or head guru person lives separate from the regular people. When he visits, he arrives through some doors that emit a bright light when opened -- the description is like that of an elevator. Something happens and the boy needs to escape. He somehow thinks that there might be life in the post apocalyptic  world and finds his way to the surface and the truth.

I read this as a child in the early '80s, but can't remember the title. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: It sounds a bit like *The City of Ember*, but the novel is from 2003.

Comment: Is it a novel or a short story?

Comment: Not a short story.  A full length children's book, possibly written for kids in 4th, 5th, or 6th grade age ranges (U.S.).